# Drupal 7 Members Directory Problem

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I created a member directory using view and it works well but I tried enable "Exposed form". I changed "Exposed form in block" to Yes & also  "Use AJAX" to Yes.
I defined "Contextual filters" to " User: Name ". then I went to Blocks and Enabled the new block and edited Only the listed pages and put the path but nothing shows up there.
here's my View : [image]
here's my block:[image]
final demo: [image]

ok, I created that with Filter Criteria, now the search fields show up at the top of the view, how can i put them in sidebar of this view?
final result: [image]

Comment: Does the user viewing the page has the View user profiles permissions to view the page?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a contextual filter, if you just want to list all the members of the website get rid off it. Contextual filter is used if you want to only show stuff about a specific user.

Comment: @undersound Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any exposed filters. Under "Filter criteria" you need to define a filter which is exposed to the user. The block will then show up

EDIT
You already set the exposed filters to be shown in a block in your views administration on the right side. Now you find a block with the exposed filters in your block administration page. Here you can set the visibility of the block - maybe just show the block under the path of this view.

Comment: @tobias-kirschdo you know how to set this filter in sidebar to shows up just for this view and page?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_filter_block for that